# Python 3.x - Run function before appending item to list

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, inheritance

In Python 3.x, is it possible to run a function before an item gets appended to a list ?

I have a class which inherits from a list, with some additionnal custom functions. I would like a series of checks to be performed on the data of any element which gets added to this list. If an added element does not meet certain criteria, the list will raise an error.

```
class ListWithExtraFunctions(list):

   def __beforeappend__(self):

      ... run some code ...
      ... perform checks ...
      ... raise error if checks fail ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `ListWithExtraFunctions.append` and call `super().append(value)` if `value` passes all the checks:

```
class ListWithExtraFunctions(list):
    def append(self, value):
        if okay():
            return super().append(value)
        else:
            raise NotOkay()
```

Answer (score 0):

This option is very similar to the solution that Vaultah wrote. It only uses “try…except” that will allow you to handle exceptions in certain way.

```
class Nw_list(list):


    def val_check(self, value):
        # Accepts only integer
        if type(value) == int:
            return value
        else:
            # Any other input type will raise exception 
            raise ValueError

    def append(self, value):
        try:
            # Try to append checked value
            super().append(self.val_check(value))                                      
        except ValueError:
            # If value error is raised prints msg
            print("You can append only int values")
```